# Sending List Items in Bot Framework sdk v4 nodeJS

Tags: node.js, botframework

So I have this code : 
`if(channelData.message.text == "test") {
   await stepContext.context.sendActivity("1. Who \n\r 2. Am \n\r 3. I ");
}`

Which gives me a message (thru FB Messenger Channel) in the image below:

[image: message result]

**Question:** Is there any template/method in bot framewwork sdk 4 (I'm using node JS) to print it in a clean list format? (removing that weird newline between 2. and 3.) Also, what if I have 
`let c= ["Who", "am", "I"]` is the any way to print it in a list format through .sendActivity? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your list propagate correctly simply remove the new line character (`\n`) and the spaces in between the preceeding text and the return character (`\r`), like so: `await stepContext.context.sendActivity('1. Who \r2. Am \r3. I');`. After that, it will format as you wish.

As for iterating thru an array of strings and formatting as a list in a single activity, the following will work:

```js
const msgArray = ['Who', 'Am', 'I'];
const message = MessageFactory.text('');
msgArray.forEach((val, index) => {
    if (!message.text) {
        message.text = `${ index + 1 }. ${ val }\r`;
    } else if (message.text) {
        console.log(message.text);
        message.text = message.text.concat(`${ index + 1 }. ${ val }\r`);
    }
});
return await stepContext.context.sendActivity(message);
```

Both of the above methods produced the same outcome shown below for me.

[image]

Hope of help!